# How to close the netrw buffer/window from any other window

Tags: key-bindings, buffers, vim-windows, netrw

I would like to have the behavior where I can run `:Vex<CR>` when pressing `<Tab>` in normal mode:

```
nnoremap <Tab> :Vex<CR>
```

... to open the netrw file tree window and then I would like to close this window when I press `<Tab>` again in any other window in this tab. Is there some way how I can get the window ID when opening the netrw window and then close it by its ID in the same tab?

Comment: Don’t map `<Tab>`! It’s the same keycode as `<C-I>`, which by default is a useful navigation command

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

`Lexplore` bug mentioned below is [fixed](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/a853089479b60b829bab1c4a0a737a073415f8a7/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim#L1275) (also see [the github comment](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1016#issuecomment-640274307)), so you can now use a single mapping to toggle the netrw window:

```
nnoremap <Tab> :Lexplore<CR>
```

However, see the comment in the code, repeated invoking of `Lexplore` is not the intended use.

**Original answer:**

There is a `Lexplore` command to toggle a netrw window on the left-hand side. However, [there is a bug](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1016) that executing it multiple times will generate a lot of empty buffers.

For now, I think stimulate's answer is quite good. I created my single-function version based on that answer (I am not a vim expert, so not sure if this is better):

```
nnoremap <Tab> :call ToggleNetRW()<CR>
function ToggleNetRW()
    if exists("g:netrw_buffer") && bufexists(g:netrw_buffer)
        exe "bd".g:netrw_buffer | unlet g:netrw_buffer
    else
        Vexplore | let g:netrw_buffer=bufnr("%")
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: I added the `&& bufexists(g:netrw_buffer)` part to check for buffer existence, so that errors are avoided in case the netrw buffer was closed in another way, i.e. not via this function.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with for now. It does not respect the current tab page yet, but maybe this could be achieved with using some kind of map data structure

```
nnoremap <Tab> :call OpenNetRW()<CR>

let g:netrw_buffer=0

function OpenNetRW()
  Vexplore
  let g:netrw_buffer=bufnr("%")
  nnoremap <Tab> :call CloseNetRW()<CR>
endfunction

function CloseNetRW()
  exe "bd".g:netrw_buffer
  let g:netrw_buffer=0
  nnoremap <Tab> :call OpenNetRW()<CR>
endfunction
```